# Blazor EditForm DataAnnotationsValidator validates unexpectedly when a custom child component changes state

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

My `EditForm` with a `DataAnnotationsValidator` contains a custom component that can modify its own state. The trivial code below provides a repro.

When the button in MyComponent is clicked, validation fires on the form. This occurs even when none of the form fields have been modified, which is unexpected and undesirable.

Is this expected behaviour? If so, how can I avoid the validation being triggered by a change to the child component?

This is occurring in a Blazor Server project running .NET 6.0.3.

### Index.razor

```
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<EditForm Model="model">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <label>
        Name:
        <InputText @bind-Value="model.Name" />
    </label>
    <MyComponent />
</EditForm>

@code {
    MyModel model = new();

    class MyModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### MyComponent.razor

```
<p>
    MyComponent: @(Switch ? "ON" : "OFF")

    <button @onclick="() => Switch = !Switch">Toggle</button>
</p>

@code {
    bool Switch = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MyComponent`, set the type to `button`:

```
<button type="button" @onclick="() => Switch = !Switch">Toggle</button>
```

For most (you can interpret this as meaning pretty much "all") browsers the default type of button is `submit`. In Blazor, validation is triggered when a form is *submitted*, in other words when a button in the `EditForm` with a type of `submit` is clicked. This is why you need to set the type to `button`.

I recommend reading [the following article](https://html.com/attributes/button-type/) about the `type` attribute on buttons for some more background.